# How get data from the website using API and R?

Tags: r, xml, api

I need to download 2 data frames from the following website. The links will show information in XML format.
https://dashboard-baltic.electricity-balancing.eu/documentation.html

1. /bids/activated/aggregated
2. /imbalance/prices

I.E. i tried following code for bids aggregated, however it shows following error:

```
data <- xmlParse("https://dashboard.electricity-balancing.eu/api/bids/activated/aggregated?start=2020-10-10&end=2020-10-16")

xml_data <- xmlToList(data)

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: '10-16'
```

How can I get this data via API?

Comment: What package does the `xmlParse` function come from. Are you sure it accepts URLs?

Comment: it comes from XML package. Not sure.

Comment: Try something like `httr::content(httr::GET("https://dashboard.electricity-balancing.eu/api/bids/activated/aggregated?start=2020-10-10&end=2020-10-16"))` instead.

Comment: yes, it is working making data frame as a list. I also found that the data i.e. for imbalance prices can be downloaded via this link `df.coba <- read.csv2(paste("https://dashboard-baltic.electricity-balancing.eu/api/imbalance/prices?report=normal&format=report&start=",Sys.Date()-100,"+22%3A00&end=",Sys.Date(),"+21%3A00&fields=_datetime&format=csv", sep=""))` However, this link gives me only 3 columns of data, but when I download it manually from Download age I have 4 columns. Do you know how to get all 4 columns?